# Is there list of previewable file types other than plain text/ASCII/source files on Github?

Tags: github, file-extension, file-format

Is there a list of file types whose formats are recognized and correctly displayed in GitHub preview, on the GitHub webpage, other than these that I know of ?

- text/ASCII/source files
- Markdown files (**.md**)
- mediawiki files
- Jupyter notebooks (**.ipynb** files)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [Advanced Search](https://github.com/search/advanced), there is a category *Written in this language*. That list shows all programming languages that github supports(their file types).

For non-related programming files, on GitHub Help, there is a section called [Working with non-code files](https://help.github.com/categories/working-with-non-code-files/) that contains different categories of files that can be displayed.

This is not a finite set of all files, maybe there is more. But it contains a lot of file types.